# My rtf documents suddenly reverted to 'Read only' documents.

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

My rtf documents suddenly reverted to 'Read only' documents. When I saved them as Word documents, they were still 'Read only'.  How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the file.
2. Click properties on the menu that appears.
3. Click the General tab, clear the Read-only check box, and then click OK.